# Tableau - Weekly Peak (of 7 days' worth of swipes) and then an Average of that

Tags: tableau-api, nested-function

I'm racking my brain how to get Tableau to do this.

Conceptually, I would think it would be a Sum (swipes) by day and then drag in week number and get the Max ( Sum(Swipes) ), but I don't know how to create such a function in Tableau.

Raw Data example:

Date | Week Number | Swipes | Org

5/1/2020 | 1 | 40 | ABC

5/1/2020 | 1 | 60 | EDF

6/1/2020 | 1 | 140 | ABC

6/1/2020 | 1 | 60 | EDF

7/1/2020 | 1 | 140 | ABC

7/1/2020 | 1 | 60 | EDF

7/1/2020 | 1 | 100 | ZXY

8/1/2020 | 1 | 100 | ABC

8/1/2020 | 1 | 300 | EDF

9/1/2020 | 1 | 200 | ZXY

10/1/2020 | 1 | 150 | ABC

11/1/2020 | 1 | 50 | EDF

11/1/2020 | 1 | 50 | ZXY

Example of the aggregated data would look as follows:

Sum of (week 1 day 1) : 100

Sum of (week 1 day 2) : 200

Sum of (week 1 day 3) : 300

Sum of (week 1 day 4) : 400

Sum of (week 1 day 5) : 200

Sum of (week 1 day 6) : 150

Sum of (week 1 day 7) : 100

Sum of (week 2 day 1) : 200

Sum of (week 2 day 2) : 200

Sum of (week 2 day 3) : 600

Sum of (week 2 day 4) : 200

Sum of (week 2 day 5) : 200

Sum of (week 2 day 6) : 450

Sum of (week 2 day 7) : 100

Weekly Peak:

Week 1 = 400
Week 2 = 600

Answer (score 1):

SUM of Swipes is correct for the first part of your requirement, the daily swipes. No need for anything fancy.

The weekly peak is different, LOD is the right way to go, as Alex suggests. Only change the formula to:

```
{ FIXED [Date]:SUM([Swipes])}
```

Take the MAX of that field with the week number in the view. That will return the MAX of the daily SUMs.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use an LOD calc (see the online help for explanation)

```
MAX( { FIXED DATETRUNC('week', [Date]) : SUM([Swipes]) } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. this really helped. A combination of your answers as well as reading.

I went with the include statement and nested the parameters I needed to slice my data within.

The actual data was much more robust and complicated. (vs the simplified data above to illustrate my dilemma)

[field] | [code]

Phase 1 : [Building_Home_Swipes] | {include [Location Building Code]:SUM([Home Swipes])}

Phase 2 : [Second+Phase_Building_Home_Swipe] | {include [BIS Flag]:SUM([Building_Home_Swipes])}

Phase 3 : [Third_Phase_Badge] | {INCLUDE [Timestamp]:SUM([Second+Phase_Building_Home_Swipe])}

REPEAT for Headcount

Phase 4 : [Weekly Avg Peak] | 100* (MAX([Third_Phase_Badge])/MAX([Third_Phase_Headcount]))

Phase 5 : [Avg_Weekly_Avg_Peak] | { INCLUDE DATETRUNC('week', [Timestamp]) : 100* (MAX([Third_Phase_Badge])/MAX([Third_Phase_Headcount])) } 
This is done as an average over a year...